# How to upload image in Amazon S3 Bucket through java?

Tags: javascript, java

The image file is coming from Node js side and an image is uploaded through 
java backend to s3 temp bucket

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

After setting credentials in your code add this:
    `AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion("ap-south-1")
            .build(); 
s3.createBucket("bucketName");
  s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "key", createfile()));`
 where createfile() is a function that returns file(image in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The following java method should be a good starting point. It relies on using the AWS EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider, which is documented along with other credentials providers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

```
package com.stackoverflow.upload;

import com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult;

import java.io.File;

public class UploadClient {

    private static final String REGION = "eu-west-1";
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucket-name";
    private static final String DESTINATION_FOLDER = "example/path/to/folder";

    public void uploadFile(File file) {

        //Create a client
        AmazonS3 s3Client =  AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(REGION)
            .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
            .build();

        //Concatenate the folder and file name to get the full destination path
        String destinationPath = DESTINATION_FOLDER + file.getName();

        //Create a PutObjectRequest
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, destinationPath, file);

        //Perform the upload, and assign the returned result object for further processing
        PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
    }
}
```